# Determine is viewWillAppear comes from opening app, or deselecting modal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I currently am loading data on app load on the initial screen.  This happens in my viewWillAppear.  I also have a modal that pops up on this screen, and when closed executes the same logic that loads the data within viewWillAppear.

How do I only load the data when the app is opened, and not when the modal is closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIViewController` provides methods to determine this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if ([self isBeingPresented] || [self isMovingToParentViewController]) {
        // being presented or pushed
    } else {
        // showing again because another VC was dismissed
    }
}
```